# Por qué me devuelve error 500 al usar $mysqli->query en una consulta con ajax?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Verán, le he estado dando vueltas un buen rato y he buscado referencias por aquí y por allá, y simplemente no encuentro caso similar...

Tengo un select que obtiene valores aleatoriamente con una consulta a la base de datos. La idea es que cuando el usuario seleccione el valor deseado, este cambio obtenga una imagen relacionada a ese valor con una consulta ajax a la misma tabla de donde se obtienen los valores del select y se muestre la imagen en el `div` correspondiente, esto a través de este script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#selector").change(function() {

    $("#selector option:selected").each(function() {

      nombre = $('#selector').val();

      $.ajax({

        data: {nombre: nombre},
        url:   'inc/snippets/img_menu.inc.php',
        type:  'post',
        beforeSend: function () {
          $("#imagen").html("...");
        },
        success: function (datos) {
          $("#imagen").html(datos);
        },
        error: function(e) {
          alert('Error: ' + e);
        }

      });

    });

  })

});
```

Sin embargo el resultado de la consulta por ajax es un error `POST «url» 500 (Internal Server Error)`. Verifiqué la url y es correcta, y comprobé el script php directamente y funciona:

```
include ('inc/conexion.php');
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$consulta = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE nombre='$nombre'";
$valores = $mysqli->query($consulta);
$valor = mysqli_fetch_array($valores);
$imagen = $valor['imagen'];

if ($imagen!=NULL) {

  echo '<img class="thumb" src="admin/assets/uploads/files/'.$imagen.'" alt="'.$nombre.'" />';

} else {

  echo '<img class="thumb" src="img/producto.jpg" alt="'.$nombre.'" />';

}
```

El script de la conexión:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost","root","root","bd");
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo 'La conexion con la base de datos falló: ', mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
```

Pero en la consulta a través de ajax se queda colgado con el alert mostrando como mensaje de error `[objectObject]`.

Entonces descubrí que este se produce cuando entra en la ecuación $mysqli->query() para recuperar el resultado de la consulta mysql, si retiro el la linea `$valores = $mysqli->query($consulta);` funciona, mostrando la imagen default a causa del que `$imagen` retorna un valor nulo. Pero en cuanto regreso la linea vuelve el error y no muestra el resultado...

Será que ya estoy muy estresado y no puedo ver lo que posiblemente es una solución? o de verdad está sucediendo algo muy extraño? Tienen alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal? Ya había hecho algo similar con codeigniter sin problema, pero esta va sin framework php de por medio.

Creo que el error debe estar en el php, particularmente en la consulta mysql, pero no logro acertar a que es...

Comment: Los errores 500 y similares indican siempre un problema en el servidor. En tu caso, haber revisado el log de errores de PHP te habría ahorrado horas y hasta días intentando saber dónde estaba el problema.

Comment: De hecho fue así como di con el error finalmente... jeje, pero pude hacerlo antes y ahorrar algunas horas, gracias por el comentario. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

En efecto, el fastidio y el cansancio puede impedir ver las más sencillas de las soluciones, basta con tomar un descanso y volver al paso...

El problema está al definir el directorio del archivo de conexión, al nivel del archivo donde se realiza la consulta ajax si es "inc/conexión.php", pero al nivel del archivo "img_menu.inc.php" hay que retroceder en la ruta... "../conexión.php" ya que "img_menu.inc.php" está en un subdirectorio dentro de "/inc".

Vaya descuido.